# How can I write a program, sequence, etc. to open pics in MS Paint, resize them and save them

Tags: vba, microsoft-paint

I know the key sequence in MS Paint to open a file, resize it, then save it.
What I want to know is how to write a program to do this repeatedly for all the files in a particular directory.
I know VBA, PHP, other programs.  I thought about writing a batch file, but from what I read, I can't send key commands to MS Paint from the cmd window once Paint is open.
Can someone point me in the right direction?  I'm sure this isn't too difficult to do, I just can't think of where to start.

Comment: Your better off following one of these examples in PHP.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649645/resize-image-in-php

Comment: If you're doing this as a programming exercise, then I applaud you - however, the particular function is so common there are a myriad free apps that can do it - there's a list here. https://www.raymond.cc/blog/most-convenient-way-to-automatically-resize-photos-for-email-im-blogging-and-web-galleries/ No endorsement of either the site or the recommendations themselves, but it will give you some idea of what's available.

Comment: I used the ImageMagick command line as Keltari described below which worked perfectly

Comment: You should upvote and Mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

The short version:

VBA does not natively support the **sendmessage**,**postmessage**, or other needed API.

The long version:

You can in a rather complex sequence build a vb. net wrapper around these functions and then invoke them from inside your VBA script via the wrapper you build.

Even then using the **sendmessage** API is going to be complicated because you need a bunch of other parameters from other.

1. Find the correct window HWND
2. Whoops the menu is a child of #1
3. Find all child objects identify which one is the menu
4. File,Edit, view and etc are children of the #3
5. Open is a child of File which is a child of menu
6. Whoops invoking the open command this way opens a new window you have to iterate through.
7. Even if you use SendMessage to invoke **CTRL O** for open you still have to find and interrogate that window.
8. After all that you have to SendMessage WM_KEYPRESS for each letter of file name
9. then Invoke the sendmessage WM_CLICK to trigger save once you figure out which child windows is Ok,Open, or Save as needed.

Its a huge complex mess do it some other way.

Answer (score 1):

THere may be libraries in programming languages to do this.  However, you are better off using a tool like [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) to do the bulk of the work.  It is designed for batch image processing.  It can be used from the command line, or with programming languages and scripts.

Comment: I'll check this out, I really like open source programs

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you so much.  I can't mark it as the best solution.  StackExchange indicates my level isn't high enough, even though it was in Stackoverflow before everything got moved here!

Answer (score 1):

**OR**

Since you're familiar with VBA, you can open the picture in MS Office (PowerPoint, Excel, Word) and use VBA to resize the picture.